# User Pool Sign-up through social provider (google, facebook)

Tags: amazon-cognito

Is it possible to do a sign-up to the user pool using a third party social provider like facebook or google?

I'm using [amazon-cognito-auth-js](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-auth-js)  amazon-cognito-auth-js but I cannot differentiate sign-in from sign-up